# Length returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking at the following code below. In my console debugger I get

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I think the idea here was concatenating two sets of nodes, however I'm not sure why I'm getting undefined

```
createNodes: function(nodes1, nodes2...){
...
var nodes = (nodes1 && nodes2) ? nodes1.concat(nodes2) : (nodes1 || nodes2),
    lenNodes = nodes.length;
//output in console, length is undefined
...
```

Comment: can your share your html code? and, how you are creating the nodes1 and nodes2?

Comment: What is `nodes1` and `nodes2`?  One of them is undefined.

Comment: how is this method called? What are the values of nodes1 and nodes2?

Comment: (nodes1 && node2)? you need to give a condition ,like !=null or something like that

Comment: `(nodes1 && nodes2)` is perfectly valid. It will evaluate to true if both nodes1 and nodes2 are truthy.

Comment: @RaphaelSerota: No, it will evaluated to `nodes2`, but it's irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: *"however I'm not sure why I'm getting undefined"* You would get `undefined` if  `nodes2` is `undefined`. I recommend to [learn how to debug](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) JS, set a break point, inspect the values and fix whatever calls that function. It's much easier for you to debug the code than it is for us.

Comment: The only case in which you will get undefined, is if BOTH nodes1 and nodes2 are undefined. If one of them is undefined (doesn't matter which one), it'll default to the truthy one. Just add a test at the beginning to make sure that at least one has a value.

Comment: Isn't it pretty obvious that `nodes` is `undefined` because one of the parameters is `undefined`? After all, the value of `nodes` is based on the parameters. I don't understand the point of this question.

Comment: It's not just *one* of the parameters. - `nodes2`has to be undefined, and `nodes1` has to be falsy. The number of incorrect statements above shows it's not completely obvious exactly what is happening, but I do agree that it seems a bit trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code checks if boths sets of nodes are truthy (probably arrays) it will concatenate them, otherwise if one of then is truthy (defined) it will use that as `nodes`.

So in short the error happens when `nodes1` has a falsy value and `nodes2` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. But I don't think if nodes2 is undefined then the result would be undefined. It will happen only if both nodes1 and nodes2 are 'undefined` because if just nodes2 is undefined then the value will be nodes1 which is empty array and all arrays consist of length property

```js
var createNodes = function(nodes1, nodes2){
nodes1 = undefined;
  nodes2 = undefined;
  
var nodes = (nodes1 && nodes2) ? nodes1.concat(nodes2) : (nodes1 || nodes2),
    lenNodes = nodes.length;
 console.log(lenNodes);
}
```

Comment: not quite - if you call `createNodes(0)` or `createNodes(false)` (for example) you'll also get undefined

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Actually, the second argument passed in, nodes2, is undefined. If one of them is undefined then that makes the whole statement undefined.

Comment: that doesn't sound right - if one of them is non-null, you should get that one back

Comment: @CupawnTae It doesn't sound right. Grassator's answer above gives a much better description.